# SharePoint Calculated Field Formula List Generation

Tags: calculated-column, export-to-excel

I have a SharePoint list content type made in legacy SharePoint. There are 143 calculated fields in this list. Is there a way to extract a complete list of all the calculations in all the columns at once so that I do not have to pull them down manually from each individual column settings?

Thank you[image: Column Settings]

[image: Column List]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to do it using Google Chrome or any other Chromium-based browser.

- Navigate to a SharePoint site
- Open Browser's dev tools (usually by clicking F12)
- Open Console tab
- Paste the following code into the console

```
(async () => {

  const payload = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" }
  }

  let results = await fetch("https://YOUR_SITE_URL.sharepoint.com/sites/YOUR_SITE/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('YOUR_LIST_TITLE')/fields", payload)
  let data = await results.json();
  let fields = data.d.results.filter(field => field.TypeAsString === "Calculated").map(field => {
    return {
      internalName: field.InternalName,
      Title: field.Title,
      Formula: field.Formula
    }
  })

  console.table(fields);

  })().catch(console.log)
```

- Replace **YOUR_LIST_TITLE**,**YOUR_SITE** and **YOUR_LIST_TITLE** accordingly.
- Run the code by pressing CTRL+ENTER
- Review the table that lists all your calculated columns

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @Denis Molotstov, your solution worked perfectly!